# Find and display a product custom field value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am trying to display a custom field value to my Woocommerce email template that was created as part of a product import.

This custom field is called **'Reference number'**.

How do I do this?

---

Edit:

This works:

```
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $sku ); ?>
        </td>
```

This doesn't:

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo $product->get_meta( 'Reference number' );
 ?>
</td>
```

The meta_key has been taken from the DB

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you have imported products with custom data and you need to get a specific custom value *(a custom field)*.

1) First you have to find out how is registered your custom field **"product code"**:

In backend product list, open an imported **product edit page**. Search in **"Custom fields" Metabox**:

[image]

If you don't find it this way, in admin product list, when hovering a product line, you can get the product ID displayed as follow:

[image]

Then in your database **using phpMyAdmin search** on `wp_postmeta` table for a specific product ID *(Here `53`)*:

[image]

You will get the list of the product metadata items… Search in the `meta_key` column:

[image]

You should find it this time.

---

2) Once you have **this meta key**, let say that `_product_code` is the meta key, you will get easily the value. There is mainly 2 ways to get and display this custom field value:

- Using the WC_Data method `get_meta()` from the defined `WC_Product` Object **`$product`**:

  ```
  echo $product->get_meta( '_product_code' );
  ```
- Using WordPress `get_post_meta()` function from a **`$product_id`** defined product ID variable:

  ```
  echo get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_code', true );
  ```

  or from the defined `WC_Product` Object **`$product`**

  ```
  echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_product_code', true );
  ```

Comment: This has been really helpful - I found the meta_key 'Reference number' but using either of your snippets and substituting 'Reference number' instead of '_product_code' gives me an error or 'undefined variable'.  Do you know how I define it?

Comment: apologies - i've edited it and added the code at the top

Comment: @J4G Can you show us or explain where have you found this meta key? You can even add a related screen shot in your question… It will be helpful.

Comment: Yes - it was taken from the DB following your instructions above. I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I do but can't right now - does in about 1 hour work? I have just added you on Skype

Comment: How do i use use get_post_meta on the cart page?